# Delete Multime Row Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

in there i have a data, i want to add a delete data where i selected. 
here my code :

```html
public function postDeleteall(){
        $id = Request::get('id');
        if($id ==''){
            Session::flash('delete', 'select first !');
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            foreach ($id as $q) {
                $qwery = DB::table('log_patrols')->where('id',$q)->get();
                foreach ($qwery as $a) {
                    DB::table('log_patrols')->where('id',$a->id)->delete();
                    $row =DB::table('log_patrol_details')->where('id_log_patrols',$a->id)->get();
                    foreach ($row as $qwe) {
                        @unlink(public_path("uploads/".$qwe->photo1));
                        @unlink(public_path("uploads/".$qwe->photo2));
                        @unlink(public_path("uploads/".$qwe->photo3));
                    }

                    $rows = DB::table('log_patrol_details')->where('id_log_patrols',$q)->delete();
                    Session::flash('delete', 'success');
                    return redirect()->back();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

when i try to print the data `$id`

[image: here]

its want to get the data id where i select, but after i try to make the code its won't work like what i want. and its only delete 1 data where i selected.
what should i do ? and what code need i change in my skript ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function postDeleteall()
        {
            $id = Request::get('id');
            if ($id == '') {
                Session::flash('delete', 'select first !');
                return redirect()->back();
            } else {
                foreach ($id as $q) {
                    $qwery = DB::table('log_patrols')->where('id', $q)->get();
                    foreach ($qwery as $a) {
                        DB::table('log_patrols')->where('id', $a->id)->delete();
                        $row = DB::table('log_patrol_details')->where('id_log_patrols', $a->id)->get();
                        foreach ($row as $qwe) {
                            @unlink(public_path("uploads/" . $qwe->photo1));
                            @unlink(public_path("uploads/" . $qwe->photo2));
                            @unlink(public_path("uploads/" . $qwe->photo3));
                        }

                        $rows = DB::table('log_patrol_details')->where('id_log_patrols', $q)->delete();
                    }

                }
                Session::flash('delete', 'success');
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting after you deleted the first patrol. Move

```
Session::flash('delete', 'success');
return redirect()->back();
```

outside of your `foreach ($id as $q)` loop.